# 'Skip' observable to string - possible?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have to adapt my data to string format. I use different `adapters`. Some of which are dependent on `Observables`, so my `adapt` method can return `string` or `Observable<string>`.
How to `skip` observable and always return `string`?
Is it possible?

```
class DoAdapt {
    adaptors: any[] = [
        // ...
    ];
    adapt(value): string {
        const result = this.adaptors[0].adapt(value);
        if (result instanceof Observable) {
            /// return string anyway
        }
        return result;
    }
}


class Adapter {
    adapt(value): string | Observable<string> {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should instead always return an Observable

Comment: Problem is that I need string form script that does not accept observables. Script is not mine

Comment: You could always `async/await` with `toPromise`, but not that sure about the syntax though ... Try providing a [mcve] on stackblitz so that I can play around ?

Comment: You could subscribe in the `/// return string anyway` section and the return the result of that subscription. But meh, I don't like it